# Bug when I show() or show2() incomplete packet

Tags: python-2.7, networking, scapy

Scapy 2.2

Even if the packet is incomplete, scapy will show all fields of the packet fields_desc.

Do you know how to tell the user that a field is not really existing ?

```
from scapy.all import *

class test(Packet):
    name = "Testing"
    fields_desc = [
        XByteField("prot", 0x12),
        XByteField("fun1", 0x1),
        XByteField("fun2", 0x2),
        XByteField("fun3", 0x3),
        XByteField("fun4", 0x4),
        XByteField("fun5", 0x5),
    ]

>>> a = test()
>>> a.show2()
###[ Testing ]###
    prot = 0x12
    fun1 = 0x1
    fun2 = 0x2
    fun3 = 0x3
    fun4 = 0x4
    fun5 = 0x5

>>> normalPacket = test()
>>> normalPacket.show2()
###[ Testing ]###
    prot = 0x12
    fun1 = 0x1
    fun2 = 0x2
    fun3 = 0x3
    fun4 = 0x4
    fun5 = 0x5

# Building an incomplete packet: the last two fields are missing
>>> incompletePacket = test(str(normalPacket)[0:len(normalPacket) - 2])
>>> incompletePacket.show2()
###[ Testing ]###
    prot = 0x12
    fun1 = 0x1
    fun2 = 0x2
    fun3 = 0x3
    fun4 = 0x4
    fun5 = 0x5
>>> str(incompletePacket)
Out[24]:
    '\x12\x01\x02\x03'
```

As you can see, the incompletePacket is correctly print with str() function, but when i want to show it (with show() or show2() functions); even the fields fun4 and fun5 are print.

Is a scapy exception error for unexpected end existing ?